# Sidekiq fails, dequeueing mongoid connection times out, probably too many connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, sidekiq, sidetiq

I am currently running `sidekiq 4.1.2`. I've never managed to be able to run more than a handfull of jobs concurrently. Recently it's been looking like I've run into an issue described in the Sidekiq's Troubleshooting WIKI called [Too many connections to MongoDB](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#too-many-connections-to-mongodb). Apparently, `mongoid 3` doesn't properly disconnect workers. However, I am using `mongoid 5.1.3`.

My issue surfaces when a job, while a few other jobs are running, tries to hit the database with a query:

```
Timeout::Error: Timed out attempting to dequeue connection after 30 sec.
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/server/connection_pool/queue.rb:190:in `wait_for_next!'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/server/connection_pool/queue.rb:176:in `block in dequeue_connection'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/server/connection_pool/queue.rb:190:in `wait_for_next!'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/server/connection_pool/queue.rb:176:in `block in dequeue_connection'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/server/connection_pool/queue.rb:172:in `loop'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/server/connection_pool/queue.rb:172:in `dequeue_connection'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/server/connection_pool/queue.rb:62:in `block in dequeue'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/server/connection_pool/queue.rb:61:in `synchronize'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/server/connection_pool/queue.rb:61:in `dequeue'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/server/connection_pool.rb:51:in `checkout'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/server/connection_pool.rb:107:in `with_connection'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/server/context.rb:63:in `with_connection'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/operation/executable.rb:34:in `execute'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/collection/view/iterable.rb:80:in `send_initial_query'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/collection/view/iterable.rb:41:in `block in each'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/retryable.rb:51:in `call'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/retryable.rb:51:in `read_with_retry'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongo-2.2.5/lib/mongo/collection/view/iterable.rb:39:in `each'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.1.3/lib/mongoid/query_cache.rb:207:in `each'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.1.3/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:121:in `each'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.1.3/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:295:in `map'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.1.3/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:295:in `map'
/home/me/applications/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mongoid-5.1.3/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:20:in `map'
/home/me/applications/myapp/releases/20160618143407/app/jobs/myjob.rb:8:in `block in perform'
```

After one job fails, the other jobs fail soon after. This most often happens after a few handfull of jobs have finished succesfully, which could indicate that those jobs don't disconnect from the database. Looking at `top` I can't see that mongo load cpu is too much.

At the same time this started to occur, I noticed that my `sidetiq 0.7.0` enabled recurring jobs were not scheduled properly. One job has stopped being queued, and others are only queued once after restart.

According to my Sidekiq web interface I have 1 queue, called **default**, with 25 threads. Max. 12-15 of them get busy at the same time.

Any idea how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: have you tried use kiqstand? https://github.com/mongoid/kiqstand

Comment: No, but it's only for Mongoid 3. According to the README I don't need it for newer versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default max pool queue size is 5. Bumping `max_pool_size` up to e.g. 25 will enable more connections to your db.

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
      options:
        max_pool_size: 25
```

Answer (score 2):

Change adding wait_queue_timeout attribute in mongoid.yml production config:

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
     uri:  mongodb://aaaaa.com:27017/mongo
     options:
       connect_timeout: 30
       wait_queue_timeout: 30
```